# Encrypt custom fields in an already released managed package

Tags: managed-package, custom-object, custom-field, encryption

We have a managed package that contains many custom fields already released (not beta). We want to enable classic encryption on some of these fields (mostly text fields) without changing the names or deleting these fields and creating new ones. The package is only installed in another org that we have created to build another package on top of the first package. So no customers are using this.

We know about the Salesforce deletion tool that we can enable through the partner portal but it has limitations such as not being able to change the field type without changing the field name.

Please let me know if you have any ideas how to do this.

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to do so, but you might contact support to confirm. In theory, if you can get them to roll back your extension package to beta, delete all the elements in it, then uninstall the package, then roll back the base package to beta, you should be able to change the types without renaming. That sounds like an awful lot of work, though, but it's probably your only choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to achieve this is to revert the package to "Beta". This can be done only because if it is not installed in any other orgs. Then, you can change the custom fields.